# Datetime conversion generic approach

Tags: python, datetime

I have the following dates:

```
4/29/2020
5/7/2020
9/10/2020
10/5/2020
11/20/2020
```

The dates extracted from Oracle are correctly read as datetime objects in Python.  However, when I manually add dates to the list in Excel, the program sees the date as string and crashes.

```
invalid input for query argument $1: '9/10/2020' (expected a datetime.date or datetime.datetime instance, got 'str')
```

This is what I am doing:

```
if isinstance(my_date,str):
             my_date = date.fromisoformat(my_date)
```

It's not working.  Is there a way to automatically convert a date in any format to datetime object?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your code to something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

if isinstance(my_date,str):
             my_date = datetime.strptime(my_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is : `datetime.strptime`

You can find documentation on how to use it here : https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior